# Invalidate a session for a filter unit test in Grails

Tags: session, testing, grails, filter, invalidation

I would like to test a filter that verifies if a session is valid but I'm not sure how to do it.

My filter is something like this.

```
class SampleFilters {
  def filters = {
    sessionFilter(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            if(request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
                //doSomething
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a unit test for this filter. What I want is when running the tests it should enter the "if" clause to perform the "doSomething". Currently, I have something like this.

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.web.FiltersUnitTestMixin;

import org.junit.*;

@TestMixin(FiltersUnitTestMixin)
class SessionFiltersTests {
  def controller

  @Test
  void testFilter() {
    controller = mockController(TestController)

    //I want to make sure when running the test it will enter the "if" clause

    withFilters(action: "testAction") { controller.testAction() }
    assert response.text
  } 
}
```

I'm still a newbie in unit test so if someone can help me I will appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. I don't know if it's the best choice but I'm getting out of ideas. This is how I left it:

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.web.FiltersUnitTestMixin;

import org.junit.*;

@TestMixin(FiltersUnitTestMixin)
class SessionFiltersTests {
  def controller

  @Test
  void testFilter() {
      controller = mockController(TestController)
      // Simulate session timeout
      controller.request.requestedSessionId = 1
      controller.request.requestedSessionIdValid = false
      withFilters(action: "test") { controller.test() }
      // Add your asserts
  }
}
```